# NiceScroll - Leaving Original Scrollbar Intact

Tags: jquery, styles, scrollbar, nicescroll

I've added the NiceScroll jQuery plugin to my page and it does exactly what I'd want it to do (eases scrolling from mouse wheel events).

However, the plugin seems geared around styling the scrollbar aswell. Is it possible to preserve the original styling of the browser's scrollbar during use of this plugin?

I've checked the [documentation](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html) and tried many parameters but can't seem to find the relevant one.

In it's current state, the scrollbar is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this still is relevant, but anyways i had the same problem, and found a solution:

Simply remove this part from the plugin, in version 3.4.0 it is at line: 706-711.

```
 if (!cap.isie9mobile) self.css(cont,{'overflow-y':'hidden'});      

 if (self.ispage&&cap.isie7) {
    if (self.doc[0].nodeName=='BODY') self.css($("html"),{'overflow-y':'hidden'});  //IE7 double scrollbar issue
    else if (self.doc[0].nodeName=='HTML') self.css($("body"),{'overflow-y':'hidden'});  //IE7 double scrollbar issue
 }
```

If you dont like editing the plugin, you have to remove the "overflow:hidden;" from the body inline style, this is what the plugin does.

When you have either removed the lines from the plugin, or in another way removed the "overflow:hidden;" from the body element. You have to hide the railbar from the plugin.

This is what i did:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html").niceScroll();
    $('.nicescroll-rails').remove();
});
```

You can see a working example [here](http://bjornnyborg.com/test/zoomSlider/index)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about leaving the original in tact but incase you can't do that you could easily style your scrollbar something like:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    border-radius: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
}
```

IMHO it looks better with some nice simple styling like that anyway, no one like to see default scrollbars :P

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately - having the scrollbars styled as they were originally is a must (as much as I'd like to develop this site otherwise).

Comment: Aaah ok no worries, just thought I would throw it out there just in case.

Comment: I don't know if you have found a solution for this yet but I know of another plugin which gives a nice scroll and leaves the original bar intact - if you look at this test page I am currently working on, you can see an example - http://zimxtrial.ukbigbuy.com/